# Control conditional rendering of router in next.js with feature flag

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-router-dom

I am migrating my React app from `react-router-dom` to `next.js`. Previously in react router, I was using a hook `useFeatureFlag` in my top level component to would return a boolean which I could use to condtionally render a page.

```
const App = (): JSX.Element => {
    const { showCalendar } = useFeatureFlags();

    return (
        <Switch>
            {showCalendar && <AppRoute path="/calendar" component={Calendar} />}
        </Switch>
    );
};
```

How can I do the same thing in next.js? Next.js doesn't have one component where all the pages are defined, but rather uses the `pages/` folder structure to infer routes, so I'm not sure how to put a boolean infront of `pages/calendar` to control the rendering of the `Calendar` component.